# Learning JavaScript for GIS?

Tags: javascript, references

How to start learning javascript for GIS?

Should learn JS first and then try to use it for gis or there is any way to learn JS for GIS from beginning?

What is the site for learning js for GIS mapping?

Comment: Are you trying to use Javascript inside of GIS program? If so, my question is why choose javascript? Python is more often used within GIS programs. Javascript related to GIS is unsally use relating to displaying GIS data on the web.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could start with this tutorial [W3Schools-JavaScript Tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/js/)

Esri has a good resource in learning through their software - [ArcGIS API for JavaScript](http://help.arcgis.com/en/webapi/javascript/arcgis../jstutorials/)

Certainly plenty of resources out there to search for. These are just a couple to look into.